# Cannot Find symbol method setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

so I currently have a list of  returned `JSON` objects as a `ListView` on my application, and I'm trying to make it so that I can click the object and then edit the details, however I'm at a bit of a loss as to why my `setOnItemClickListener` isn't working, code below

```
package mmu.tom.linkedviewproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView GetAllDevicesListView;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.GetAllDevicesListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.GetAllDevicesListView);

    new GetAllDevicesTask().execute(new ApiConnector());

    GetAllDevicesTask.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

        try

        {
            //GetDevice that was clicked
            JSONObject deviceClicked = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);


            //Send DeviceId
            Intent showDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceDetailsActivity.class);
            showDetails.putExtra("deviceID", deviceClicked.getString("deviceID"));
        }

        catch(
        JSONException e
        )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });

}

public void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray){

    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    this.GetAllDevicesListView.setAdapter((new GetAllDeviceListViewAdapter(jsonArray,this)));


}

private class GetAllDevicesTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

        // it is executed on Background thread

         return params[0].GetAllDevicesState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

     setListAdapter(jsonArray);



    }


}
```

}

Comment: It should be getAllDevicesListView (variables do not start with capital letter !). And yeah you have to set the itemClickListener on the ListView not the class name of GetAllDevicesTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not taking List view object.

Change to this.

```
GetAllDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

    try

    {
        //GetDevice that was clicked
        JSONObject deviceClicked = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);


        //Send DeviceId
        Intent showDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceDetailsActivity.class);
        showDetails.putExtra("deviceID", deviceClicked.getString("deviceID"));
    }

    catch(
    JSONException e
    )

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: That's perfect! thank you! i was following an online guide so i was pretty much copying there code, but i must have missed something!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `setOnItemClickListener` on a `ListView` but on a class name.

Change

```
GetAllDevicesTask.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

to

```
GetAllDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```